# Redirecting HTTP request to different server

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking

I am trying to implement a failover system. So I have created a monitoring server which is suppose to route the request to different application server which is alive.

So far I have designed a small monitoring server and trying to route the request using `HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n` status code. But I am not able to redirect to my virtual machine although I can access that directly on my browser by typing the url.

Routing code -

```
class Connection extends Thread{
    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedReader din;
    OutputStreamWriter outWriter;

    public Connection(Socket clientSocket){
        try{
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "ASCII"));
            outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Connection: " + e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
        String line = null;
        while((line = din.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println("Read" + line);
            if(line.length()==0)    
                break;
        }
        //here write the content type etc details:
        System.out.println("Someone connected: " + clientSocket);

        }catch(EOFException e){
            System.out.println("EOF: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO at run: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
                routeRequest(outWriter);
                outWriter.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to close the socket");
            }
        }
    }

    public void routeRequest(OutputStreamWriter outWriter){
        try {
            outWriter.write("HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n");
            outWriter.write("Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 13:09:20 GMT\r\n");         
            outWriter.write("Content-type: text/plain\r\n");
            outWriter.write("Server: vinit\r\n");           
            outWriter.write("Location: http://192.168.74.128:8080/Stateless/index.html");
            outWriter.write("Connection: Close");
            outWriter.write("\r\n\r\n");
//          String responseStr = "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello world from my server</body></html>\r\n";
//          outWriter.write(responseStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But on browser instead of routing I get No data received page.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

**PS: I a able to display dummy hello world page if I go with status 200**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use a ready made solution?

Comment: sorry but how to do that? Also i really want to do this using sockets so if you can please help me

Comment: You don't write application servers yourself (hopefully), so there's no reason to write load balancers either.

Comment: Kayaman, I don't but this is my assignment and i have to do it. So Can you please help me

Comment: I have edited the question with whole code.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling `start()` in the constructor. That's not very clean. You also don't seem to be calling `routeRequest` anywhere?

Comment: Extremely sorry, the line got deleted somehow, anyways, please see updated code. Thanks for being with me

Comment: If you're using Chrome, press F12 to get the developer console. You can see what the server is actually responding with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Location:` header lacks an end of line indicator.

```
outWriter.write("Location: http://192.168.74.128:8080/Stateless/index.html\r\n");
```

Missing this will cause your `Connection:` header to become part of the redirected URL. The client will remain connected to the server, unless your server is closing explicitly after delivering this response.

Even if the client times out and closes the connection, it might treat the URL as invalid. If it does redirect, then the page will not be found, since the path would be something like:

> `/Stateless/index.htmlConnection: Close`